# absolute_codec_string not working in dialplan

Tags: freeswitch

I got some trouble with using `absolute_codec_string` param.

My call scenario is pretty simple: caller <--> FS <--> callee.

My caller compose `m=audio 7078 RTP/AVP 8 0 101` in its INVITE and I'm doing 
 `<action application="bridge" data="{absolute_codec_string=PCMU}sofia/gateway/callee/$1"/>` 
 in the dialplan.

I expected FS to use only PCMU `m=audio 22952 RTP/AVP 0 101` talking to the callee

But FS still use `m=audio 22952 RTP/AVP 8 0 101` in the INVITE to the callee.

Note that when I'm using `originate` application in fs_cli, things are good.

`originate {absolute_codec_string=PCMU}sofia/gateway/caller/100 &bridge({absolute_codec_string=PCMA}sofia/gateway/callee/100`

then I have FS with proper behavior in transcoding, caller has `m=audio 31184 RTP/AVP 0 101` received, and callee has `m=audio 21922 RTP/AVP 8 101` received.

Not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit** 
I was using FS media_proxy, so `absolute_codec_string` won't work, any another way to limit codecs used for callee to fulfill my purpose?
e.g: caller use PCMA,PCMU, I want to cut PCMA out of SDP and offer PCMU only to callee
rgds, 
Loi Dang

Comment: please check the vars.xml and remove the absolute codec string if its set there

Comment: many tks @suren, please see my Edit

Answer (score 0):

Guess I have the answer for my own question
Briefly, I modify the whole remote sdp with variable `switch_r_sdp` instead of dealing with `absolute_codec_string`

```
<condition field="${switch_r_sdp}" expression="/(.*)(m=audio \d+ RTP\/AVP)([ \d]+)(.*)/s" break="never">
  <action application="set" data="switch_r_sdp=$1$2$ 8 101$4"/>
  <!-- Then just call bridge normally -->
</condition>
```

More info: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Codec+Negotiation#CodecNegotiation-Modifyingthecodecwhenusingproxymediamode

rgds,
Loi Dang